# what is it about jquery that it transforms a html element into an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginning to learn jquery and basically a lot of aspects of jquery interest me. Now I have been writing small snippets in jquery lately and I am pretty comfortable now .

I have a small curiosity, have a look at the code below :

```
<a href="#">Click here</a>
```

Jquery code ::

```
elem_jquery = $('a');

elem_js = $('a')[0];

console.log(elem_jquery);

console.log(elem_js);
```

now `elem_jquery` prints the following ::

```
Object { 0: <a>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → jquery-object.html, selector: "a" }
```

and elem js prints the following ::

```
<a href="#">
```

what i am  really curious to know is , what is it about jquery that transforms

```
<a href="#">
```

into

```
 Object { 0: <a>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → jquery-object.html, selector: "a" }
```

?

does this have something to do with [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) ?

Comment: It is an object, `$` does basically `new jQuery`, where `Object` is an instance of the `jQuery` constructor.

Comment: @elclanrs makes sense , but does't make total sense :D

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't transform an html element into an object. What it does is it takes the reference to the dom element and wraps it inside the jQuery object. The original dom element is still there inside the jQuery object.

Comment: In the case of `elem_js = $('a')[0];` you lost any reference of that element wrapped by jQuery and it's methods.
Also, worth noting that selectors are returned as an Array of HTMLElements. And since it's an Array: `[0]` gets the first key - which holds the native HTML element object.

Answer (score 1):

Sizzle is the selector engine within jQuery; meaning it allows jQuery to find DOM elements based on strings like `.className` or `#idName` or more complex ones like `element[attr='value']`, and so on.

So, when you run `$(selector)` jQuery uses sizzle to find all DOM elements that match that query, then it returns them *wrapped into a jQuery object*. (Generally these DOM elements are represented in JavaScript as [HTMLElement objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). Which is what you get when access `$(selector)[0]`.)

Now you can run functions like `$(<css-selector>).html()`, `$(<css-selector>).css()`, etc. on the jQuery object which will in turn affect the wrapped DOM elements and to always get the access to the wrapped [HTMLElement object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) jQuery provides these `[<index>]` like  `$(selector)[0]` .

Answer (score 1):

`$('a')` is a selector.  jQuery takes it and looks for all `anchor` elements, then returns an object with its results.  That's why it has an attribute length of 1.  It only found one.

By doing `$('a')[0]`, you are telling jQuery to fetch the DOM element itself.
This is equal to the more readable `$('a').get(0)`.

But if you do `$('a').first()` you will get another jQuery object that is representative of the anchor DOM object.  This has the benefit of being able to do things like `$('a').first().attr('href')` - which returns the `href` attribute.

Basically, jQuery creates objects that can do things that make your job easier and your code more readable than pure ugly javascript.